# Managing Visual Studio from command line

Tags: visual-studio-2015, command

Is there a way of managing Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 from the command line. For example, you could use the commands in the command line to check in to team projects.

Thanks

Comment: what source control are you using? also what other commands do you need?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Team Foundation Server. In terms of other commands, maybe build solution, connecting to team projects and maybe changing team project settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to your Programs menu > Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 > Visual Studio Tools > **Visual Studio 2005 Command Prompt**.

this command prompt has all the necessary .NET environment variables set for the the command line session. You can change directory to your solution directory and run:

```
Msbuild.exe mySolution.sln
```

For checking the code in (VS 2010 below):

```
tf checkin
```

For VS 2013/2015:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands